# How to make a customable message in Twilio Voice call

Tags: twilio

i've successfully make a voice call with twilio like this:

```
  $call = $client->calls->create(
    $toNumber, $fromNumber,
    array("url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")
  );
```

the above code will call to the `$toNumber` with twilio demo message, when i try to use TwiML to create the dynamic message like this:

```
$response = new TwiML();
$response->say('Votre otp est 2234', ['voice' => 'woman', 'language' => 'fr']);

$call = $client->calls->create(
    $toNumber, $fromNumber,
    $response
  );
```

i got an error like this:

> [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: Url parameter is required. For
>   more information, see http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't send the TwiML to Twilio when you make a call like that. You need to send a URL that Twilio will send an HTTP request to when the call connects (like in the original example). So, to fix your code you should replace the demo URL with your own URL.

```
  $call = $client->calls->create(
    $toNumber, $fromNumber,
    array("url" => $YOUR_URL_HERE)
  );
```

That URL can be your own application, or something like a [TwiML Bin](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/11/twiml-bins-a-serverless-and-codeless-way-to-try-twilio.html) or [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions). Check out this article to see [how to respond with TwiML to a request from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-respond-to-incoming-phone-calls-php).

I notice that you are building something for one time passwords too. You might be interested in checking out the [Authy API that can implement and deliver OTP codes via calls, SMS and app](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api).

Comment: so i need to regenerate xml file everytime i need to load custom message ?

Comment: Well, you could use a static XML file hosted somewhere. But since you are sending OTPs, you likely want something dynamic, like a PHP file that generates the right code for the right user.

Comment: @philnash so there is no possibility to send custom text-to-spech voice call without additional request to TwiML? About OTP codes there is a requirement that there must be registered user on Twilio side which is not acceptable in my project. So at least there is a possibility to send custom parameters and make them somehow dynamically used in TwiML?

Comment: [The Twilio 2FA API no longer needs you to register your users with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/improving-user-privacy-two-factor-authentication). For voice calls you do need to handle a request and respond with TwiML. You could make this easier on yourself by using a [TwiML Bin and a template](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/230878368-How-to-use-templates-with-TwiML-Bins) then adding the code as a URL parameter to the TwiML Bin URL and passing that as your URL parameter.